# PHP MySQLi - Check user privilege

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i am trying to implement a PHP function that will check if a user has a privilege to execute a specific database query (e.g. CREATE TABLE).

I have checked the MySQLi manual at:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

..but i could not find any API to check connected user privileges.

What would be the recommended way to check if a user has a specific privilege in MySQL using PHP 5?

Comment: Have you tried looking at [Privilege System Grant Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant-table-structure.html) or [`SHOW GRANTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html)?

Comment: Hmm. I checked SHOW GRANTS, but i was looking at some cleaner way to accomplish this task. However, if there is no other way i will go down the SHOW GRANTS path. Thanks.

Comment: I gave you another link, that might be closer to what you want.

Comment: i will try it as well. The privilege tables query looks like a cleaner approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do not actually understand WHY do you need such a query. If you run a non-privileged query to MySQLi via PHP, `mysqli_query` statement would return an error, won't it?..

Comment: Yes.. but the whole point is not to handle and parse cryptic errors, and instead have a nice clean check.